# Can I use 2 different Columns of Data for the same axis & same series in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, charts

I have a simple dataset in Excel showing `Players`, `Win Count` & `Win %`

[image]

I'd like on my Bar Chart to keep the % on the Vertical Axis like it currently...
But I'd also like to put the Win Count on the bar chart to annotate each Column. Something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Option 1: Use a second "hidden" series

This is possible by including the `Wins` column as a second series in the chart and hide it like so:

- Add a [secondary vertical axis](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-or-remove-a-secondary-axis-in-a-chart-HP001234165.aspx#BMsecondaryverticalaxis) for the `Wins` series.
- Format the secondary axis and chose a font color to match the color of your background and also hide its vertical line (so it appears there is no secondary axis).
- Now you can [add data labels](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-or-remove-data-labels-in-a-chart-HP001234166.aspx) to the `Wins` series that show the value of the series on top of the bars.

This works because the relative height of the bars is the same for the `Wins` and `Win %` columns. So while it looks like you are displaying only the data for `Win %`, you are actually showing the data for `Wins` on top of it. From the legend you will want to delete the hidden series, as it would otherwise give away there being two series in the dataset.

This is what the resulting chart looks like:

[image: Excel chart]

## Option 2: Manually edit the data labels

If you only create the chart once and its underlying data doesn't change, there is also a simpler option. After [adding data labels](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-or-remove-data-labels-in-a-chart-HP001234166.aspx) to the `Win %` series, you can just click the labels twice (two single clicks, not a double click) and [enter a formaula](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/05/05/change-data-labels-in-charts/) for each.

Comment: Very good. That's slightly better than the other option I found which involved adding formula to each individual data label above each column

Comment: +1 for option 1, definitely the right answer for this scenario. You can also keep the legend and just delete the legend entry for the hidden series if you want to

Comment: @AdamV You're right. Totally forgot, you could delete individual entries from the legend. I have updated my answer to reflect that. Thanks for the tip!